# priority vise All methods of a (xib,.m) file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am beginner in iPhone.I want to know what is the priority of execution of all methods like(viewdidload,viewwillappear,viewdidunload and other remaining...).

Please tell me anyone what is actual flow of the execution in iphone application.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on uiviewcontrollers in the apple docs everything is there. It's pretty straightforward or I would list it here.